# Spring Boot 2.7 to SprintBoot3 Migration Issue with HttpClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am facing issue when I try to migrate to SpringBoot 3 from Spring Boot 2.

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.net.Proxy.Type;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients; 
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate; 

@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class RestTemplateConfig{

int timeout=10000;
int readTimeout=10000;
int retryCount=3;
int timeToLive=5000;
String rProxy=proxy.test.com;
String rPort=80;

public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
return new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {

Httphost proxy new HttpHost(rProxy, Integer.parseInt(rPort));

SocketConfig socketConfig=SocketConfig.custom()
                          .setSoTimeout(timeout)
                          .build();

RequestConfig requestConfig=RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout)
                            .setConnectTimeout(timeout)
                            .setSocketTimeout(timeout)
                            .build(); 

HttpClient httpClient=HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy)
                                          .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
                                          .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                                          .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryCount, true))
                                          .setConnectionTimeToLive(timeToLive, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                          .build(); 

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory rf=new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient):
rf.setConnectTimeout(timeout); rf.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
rf.setConnectionRequestTimeout(timeout);

return rf;
}
```

I am getting error:

> The constructor HttpComponsentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient) is undefined.

It seems in SpringBoot3 HttpComponsentsClientHttpRequestFactory constructor only takes org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient

I made the following changes [Changed the classes to httpClient5]:

```
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.HttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;
```

But getting error:

> The method setDefaultSocketConfig(SocketConfig) is undefined for the type HttpClientBuilder

```
HttpClient httpClient=HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy)
              .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
              .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
              .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryCount, true))
              .setConnectionTimeToLive(timeToLive, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              .build();
```

Is there any equivalent method to setDefaultSocketConfig or any other way I can attain same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `ConnectionManager` with the `SocketConfig` and pass that `ConnectionManager` to the `HttpClientBuilder` you are using.
For example,

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
              .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
              .build();
```

and then,

```
HttpClient httpClient=HttpClients.custom().setProxy(proxy)
          .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
          .build()
```

You can also set the `timeToLive` in a `ConnectionConfig` and pass that to `ConnectionManager` as well, like

```
final ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = ConnectionConfig
          .custom()
          .setTimeToLive(TimeValue.ofMilliseconds(...))
          .build();
```

Then,

```
  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
              .setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig)
              .setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig)
              .build();
```

You can pass this `ConnectionManager` to the `HttpClientBuilder`, the same way as we did before.